# applescript word searching revisions

Tags: ms-word, applescript, revision

I am trying to organize the revisions in a Word document.  I am obviously missing something pretty basic, as I can't get very far.

The following script

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"

    set activeDoc to active document

    set revCount to count of revisions of activeDoc

    set aRev to first item of revisions of activeDoc

    set auth to author of aRev
    set when to date value of aRev

end tell
```

generates the following:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    get active document
        --> active document
    count every revision of active document
        --> 1275
    get item 1 of every revision of active document
        --> current application
Result:
error "The variable aRev is not defined." number -2753 from "aRev"
```

The error occurs on the "set auth" reference.  I have tried various items in the list with the same result.  I also noticed from the dictionary that text ranges can contain revisions, but even with a range spanning the entire document I get zero from a count of revisions from it.

Comment: OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), Microsoft Word 2011 (latest updates for both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of the following should fix the immediate problem:

```
set aRev to first revision of activeDoc
```

or

```
set theRevs to the revisions of activeDoc
set aRev to the first item of theRevs
```

(I thought that the following should work, but right now I have forgotten why not)

```
set aRev to the first item of (revisions of activeDoc)
```

Comment: That first one got my simple sample to work.  Now the second one is timing out so I am working on that.  I have seen this sort of behaviour before but I have never seen any documentation to help me understand how the collections work.

Comment: Re. Documentation, I suspect the best you will find is general A/S documentation and sample code. I do not think Microsoft ever produced any for the AppleScript interfaces to Office 2011 (except possibly Outlook). They produced an A/S guide for Word 2004 or 2008 (gone, I think). Now that they have also removed the 2011 Mac-specific VBA documentation, we are left with (a) the object model info. available within VBE, (b) object model documentation for Windows Word on MSDN, not always correct for Mac, (c) the AppleScript dictionary for Word, (d) Other general stuff, and (e) trial and error.